# PhotoShop CC 2018 - Video editing - Timeline shows neither timecode nor frames

Tags: adobe-photoshop, video, configuration

Edit: I can now provide images. Also, Aaron's obviously on a Mac, whereas I'm on Windows.

Good day,

The title gives most of the relevant information. Maybe these data are, as well:

- Photoshop is build 19.1.6, if that makes a difference
- I'm running on Windows 10, on a desktop computer

So, I get these notches/fenceposts that show at regular intervals on the Timeline, but neither frame counts nor timecode shows on them.

I'm a technical writer who's fairly new to PS, although an enthusiastic learner. HOWEVER...I have an absolute wizard in-house with me—15 years of experience. He doesn't have a lot of experience with editing video in PS, but he can't figure it out, either.

Between the two of us, we've looked at every setting that we think could be relevant, and nada.

I have already Googled. Any and all suggestions are welcome, though.

Thank you,

CoolWahad
[image: My timeline (Photoshop CC 2018 on WIndows 10]

[image: Aaron Nace's timeline in his PS video-editing videos on YouTube (Branded PhLearn)]

Comment: I can't launch CC2019 at the moment.. but have you checked the **Timeline Panel options**?

Comment: Don't use photoshop for video editing, there are better tools in the Adobe package for that.

Comment: @Scott, I have checked those options. I can change it to either Frame Number or Timecode, and I see some visual changes from that. Status bar-ish thing in lower left switches back and forth from frames to timecode.

It's in the top area, same area where the scrub dragger is (best name I can give it, sorry, don't know if there's a better name) that I'm not seeing what I see in the PHLearn video. On the "fenceposts," he's got indications of time, or frames. I just have the fenceposts. 

They delineate regular divisions, but what's each one's value? It's not one second, in timecode mode.

Comment: @Luciano, 1) One of our corporate values is "Spend money like it's your own," 2) I don't need anything that fancy, and 3) That's another app to learn. I'm just after a bit more customizability for some short video segments on what are, for now, internal-only pages. I've been uploading to Adobe Spark, to edit a bit and do titling, but the free version is quite limited. Not gonna pay for the upgrade.

Comment: Ah, it's more clear now. You don't see the timecodes on any timeline zoom levels? What's project FPS?

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy - To answer your questions: 1) No, no timecodes or frames in the timeline at any zoom level, and 2) it's 23.976 fps.  
Right now, I'm just working with the sample videos that accompany the tutorials I'm going through.  
There are two other video sources I might wind up working on with this, and maybe I'll see a different result with one or both of them.  One is short screen-capture sequences, and the other is videos from a choral concert in which I recently took part.

Comment: Have you tried to reboot, disable GPU in Photoshop Preferences, try a different Photoshop version from Creative Cloud? That is weird indeed!

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy - I reboot only sporadically, but I can try that. I can try disabling the GPU. the GPU. I can't remember where that is, but my in-house wizard can help, or Google. I do not have the option to try a different version of Photoshop. I implied in an earlier comment that my employer was reluctant to spend money. In fact, in terms of what I've asked them for, they're been incredibly generous. I'm a tech writer, they got me PS and AI, which...yes, there are GIMP and InkScape, but I wanted to learn industry-standard tools. I don't want to push that, though.

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy - Rebooted, turned off GPU in PS (found it), no difference. I had been working with a saved TIF file, referencing multiple video segments. I tried opening just one of those, an MP4, and no difference. I'm stumped!

Comment: With Creative Cloud subscription you can install most other Photoshop versions from Creative Cloud app: no need to buy anything. That's something I'd try, sometimes it helps in the worst situations. Also, have you tried to create a new file with a video timeline?

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy - creating a new file: no difference. I did not know that about Creative Cloud - I will look into installing a different PhotoShop version.

Answer (score 0):

A screenshot of your setup would be helpful because I don't think there's an option to hide it and it's quite visible. It should be here:

[image]

And in the `Panel Options` you can set it to display time code or frame number.

Comment: I will add screenshots, soon. it had occurred to me even before I posted that pictures would be very useful, in this situation.